# Proof of a convergence of a given probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-writing

I am studying probability theory and convergence is something that is very new to me. So I am trying to solve the mentioned problem and any guidance is appreciated.
Let $X_n \xrightarrow d $ $X$, $f(n) ↑ ∞$. Prove that $P(X_n ≥ f(n)) → 0$ as $n → ∞$.

All the sequence convergence that I see uses predominantly markov's or chebysev inequality to prove such expression. I guess this will also use markov's inequality also to give me the desired result. But I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Markov inequality is not needed. Just the definition of convergence in distribution gives the result.

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $T$ such that $P(X>T)<\epsilon$. We may also assume that $T$ is a  continuity point for the distribution of $X$. Now $P(X_n >T)  \to P(X>T)<\epsilon$ so there exists $N$ such that  $P(X_n >T) <\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Also, there exists $M$ such that $f(n) >T$ for $n \geq M$. Now $n \geq \max \{N,M\}$ implies $P(X_n \geq f(n)) \leq P(X_n >T) <\epsilon$.